# c# Enum Function Parameters

Tags: c#, enums, function-parameter

As a follow on from [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492115/c-enums-as-function-parameters)

How can I call a function and pass in an Enum?

For example I have the following code:

```
enum e1
{
    //...
}

public void test()
{
    myFunc( e1 );
}

public void myFunc( Enum e )
{
    var names = Enum.GetNames(e.GetType());

    foreach (var name in names)
    {
        // do something!
    }

}
```

Although when I do this I am getting the 'e1' is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable' Error message. Any ideas to help?

I am trying to keep the function generic to work on any Enum not just a specific type? Is this even possible?... How about using a generic function? would this work?

Comment: @TK, see my recent edit for typesafe.

Comment: I'd like an explanation _why_ you want to do this. To me it looks like you try to find a solution for a problem that wouldn't exist if you'd rethink your aproach from a few steps before so an explanation might help finding a solution for the real problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use a generic function:

```
    public void myFunc<T>()
    {
        var names = Enum.GetNames(typeof(T));

        foreach (var name in names)
        {
            // do something!
        }
    }
```

and call like:

```
    myFunc<e1>();
```

**(EDIT)**

The compiler complains if you try to constraint `T` to `Enum` or `enum`.

So, to ensure type safety, you can change your function to:

```
    public static void myFunc<T>()
    {
        Type t = typeof(T);
        if (!t.IsEnum)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Type is not Enum");

        var names = Enum.GetNames(t);
        foreach (var name in names)
        {
            // do something!
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 9):

Why not passing the type?
like:

```
 myfunc(typeof(e1));

public void myFunc( Type t )
{
}
```

Comment: if I use "if ( e is Enum )" or the 'as' statement, then I get an error "Cannot convert type 'System.Type' to 'System.Enum' via a reference conversion, boxing conversion, unboxing conversion, wrapping conversion, or null type conversion"

Comment: You can still use Enum.GetNames(t)

Comment: How could I type-safe this to ensure that ony enums are used instead of any type?

Comment: Use typeof(Enum).IsAssignableFrom(t) - that will return false of t does not represent an Enum type.

Answer (score 5):

You are trying to pass the type of the enum as an instance of that type - try something like this:

```
enum e1
{
    foo, bar
}

public void test()
{
    myFunc(e1.foo); // this needs to be e1.foo or e1.bar - not e1 itself
}

public void myFunc(Enum e)
{
    foreach (string item in Enum.GetNames(e.GetType()))
    {
        // Print values
    }
}
```

Comment: I am aware that I canpass individual values like this. I am looking to pass a generic Enum to a function to say print all the values not just one.

Comment: This will print all the values. Use Enum.GetNames(e.GetType()).

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
public void myFunc( e1 e ) { // use enum of type e}
```

instead of

```
public void myFunc( Enum e ) { // use type enum. The same as class or interface. This is not generic! }
```

Comment: I was trying to keep the function generic to work on any Enum not just a specific type?